# Error while assigning an SQL Query to RowSource in VBA in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to run an SQL Query in VBA to populate a combobox. I'd like the combobox to display all Start Times ([Schedule Data].[ApptStart]) on a given date, chosen from a date picker ([ApptDate] on the form.) I've tried various iterations of the statement below but can't seem to get anything but errors and a blank combo box.

```
Me.ComboTimeList.RowSource =
 "SELECT [Schedule Data].[ApptStart]
  FROM [Schedule Data]
  WHERE [Schedule Data].[ApptDate] = #" & Me.[ApptDate] & "#"
```

I don't know if this is just a syntax issue or if I'm missing some bigger concept. Any help is appreciated. I'm happy to provide any additional needed info. Thanks!

edit: The full error message reads:

Syntax error in date in query expression '[Schedule Data].[ApptDate] = #'

Sorry for neglecting to include that in the original message.

Comment: What is the full text of the error message you get when assigning that statement to the combo box's `RowSource`?

Comment: The full error message reads:

Syntax error in date in query expression '[Schedule Data].[ApptDate] = #'

 ... Sorry for neglecting to include that in the original message.

Comment: Use a string variable *strRowSource* to hold your `SELECT` statement.  Then you can do `Debug.Print strRowSource` and `Me.ComboTimeList.RowSource = strRowSource`  You can view the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there.  Copy the `SELECT` statement text and add it into your question.  Let us know if the error is different than the one you got before.

Comment: Thanks, HansUp. I ended up using Debug.Print and found that my [ApptDate] field was returning Null. I'd move this snippet of code to a Change event so it was running the query when I clicked the field instead of when I chose the date (or at least that's what I'm presuming.) Whoops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code should have been:

```
Me.ComboTimeList.RowSource =
 "SELECT [Schedule Data].[ApptStart] & _
  FROM [Schedule Data] & _ 
  WHERE [Schedule Data].[ApptDate] = #" & Me.[ApptDate] & "#;"
```

Additionally, Me.[ApptDate] was returning "Null" because I had the code in the Change event instead of AfterUpdate event.